# Node.js encrypt RSA[XML]

Tags: c#, node.js, xml, encryption, rsa

I need to encrypt a string in Node.js using the key created in C# (XML format)

**Public Key:**

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>mlDk9dIwcGJ+sS7kCOiG/xr/1RkM7v7/bUExalwSj7Q/Ul575l4cUGR1ZjC3BtEgmMZjW6xSRTCkgp0WMpdnXGmygV0mQbrAP32NTGoMoWgjTIevBbd+yOMfY8E87bUG0sYUA8+Wk55iEPk3O0Ua5FiLNWIqGTbrF2A5iSp1voc=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You parse the XML using an XML parser, then retrieve the two base 64 values and decode those: the modulus and the public exponent. Then you generate a key using the two components for whatever library you are using.

I could not directly see if the number encoded is big- or little endian: Mickeysoft doesn't specify that, but the lack of reversal routines in other language implementations leads me to believe that the bytes represent a big endian encoding.

The fact that the leftmost byte of the modulus is an even value is probably a good indication as well as n = p * q, and if p & q are primes and thus odd, so the result of the calculation is then odd as well.

Comment: The `ToXmlString` method produces a value compliant with https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/#sec-RSAKeyValue, which specifies Big Endian.